# How best to build a model in this MVC

Tags: ios, iphone, model-view-controller

This is an MVC best practice question. I'll explain my design and then you guys can tell me if it sounds correct.

I have a view that shows text data from a PDF similar to iBooks called TextView.h. It has a UIScrollView that uses paging to allow the reader to swipe through pages.

I assume all that logic of loading and breaking up text into pages should be done by a model class.
So for the best practice I was thinking I create a model class and have it be responsible for 
1) Opening the pdf
2) Have a public interface that the view controller can use to query text data based on the page that it wants

I have a TextViewController.h that is a delegate of TextView.h. The TextViewController would be responsible for 
1) Loading the text view
2) Querying the model and using the result to populate the view. e.g.

```
UILabel *label = [model getTextForPage:1];
[myView addPage:label];
```

3) Give the textViewController a delegate method that is triggered each time the user turns a page in the view. i.e. the view controller would listen to the view's didEndDecelerating method. When this happens the viewController can grab the text for the new page and pass it to the view e.g.

```
  UILabel *label = [model getTextForPage:x];
    [myView addPage:label];
```

Let me know if all this sounds correct. Thanks!

Comment: In general, your model class should not know anything about how the data is being presented, including the fact that it's being presented with a `UILabel` object. Therefore, having a model method that returns a `UILabel` is not good separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your statement:

> I assume all that logic of loading and breaking up text into pages should be done by a model class

is not correct because models only hold values, and all the processing performed on data should be done in the controller in the MVC pattern.

For example, if you want to add two numbers, then you have to hold the values in the model, perform the addition process in the controller, and display the result in the view.

If you need to break up text into pages, that logic should be done in the controller.

In iOS, the controller and view are combined into a view controller, so there is no need to create another view. In your example, you can create a view and handle the logic in the view controller, and that's fine, but but you can't process data in the model, as you've done in `getTextForPage`. Instead, move this logic into a method in the view controller than can return text, and then load this text into the view label. This method can get the required detail from the model object.

In summary, the model holds the data, the process of creating a page is done in view controller, and the result is loaded into the view that you create.

For more detail on MVC in iOS, refer to these links, which should help you:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-design-patterns-model-view-controller-part-3

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html

Answer (score 1):

**Model**     - Just holds Values.
**View**      - All that you can see by your eyes on screen.
**Controller**- Controls the way you want your View to function

In your case,

TextView.h is your **View**. Covers all **display and scrollView & paging**.

All the rest of the logic **loading and breaking up text into pages**, **Opening the pdf**, **query text data based on the page**, **Loading the text view** comes under TextViewController.h and that is your **Controller**

The data you show in those pages is your **Model**.